# How to preserve, or at least sort edge attributes when creating a graph from a shapefile in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, shapefile

I've made a graph in networkx from a shapefile using :

```
import networkx as nx
layer = nx.read_shp(path)
G=layer.to_undirected()
```

After manipulating its edge attributes, I have to keep the results in a shapefile, so:

```
nx.write_shp(G,out_path)
```

The problem is, this new shapefile will have completely random order of attributes; understandable, since the attributes are stored in a dictionary. I couldn't fix this with OrderedDict either:

```
# Does NOT work
for edge in G.edges(data=True):
    edge = list(edge)
    edge[2] = OrderedDict(sorted(edge[2].items()))
    edge=tuple(edge)
```

Is there a way to sort, or change the order of attributes for each edge?

Comment: Good start, really, your description is very readable. But your code is a bit incomplete, where the `nx` comes from? (full working/breaking example is best, ideally as short as possible but complete from description of your problem point of view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for edge in G.edges(data=True):
    edge = list(edge)
    edge[2] = OrderedDict(sorted(edge[2].items()))
    edge=tuple(edge)
```

has no effect on the output (or the contents of the object pointed to by `G`), because by doing:

```
edge = tuple(edge)
```

you are only modifying the local variable `edge`; this will *not* affect the value returned by `G.edges(data=True)`, even less the internal state of `G`. This holds for *any* (Python) program whatsoever and is in no way related to networkx or your program specifically.

So unless you write your own algorithm to serialize and dump the data to a file, or unless you can tell `networkx` how it should serialize the data, there's no way to change the file content. ...unless I'm missing something, that is, but according to http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.nx_shp.html, `write_shp` is not configurable in the manner you need.